# How to see NSLog output with Apportable?

Tags: apportable

How to see `NSLog` or any plain `printf` output with Apportable? I run my program with `apportable debug` and `run` the *gdb*, but there's no output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSLog and printf are piped to the android logging system. So in order to see your messages; invoke adb logcat. That will allow you to see logging.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `apportable log | grep NSLog`, it's shows only NSLog's.

Answer (score 0):

Open two terminal windows. Type apportable log | grep AppName on one of them. Then just do apportable debug on the other one.